# Makefile with LaTeX dir

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It is a long time ago, that I worked with GNU make, since then I forgot a lot. :-(

I have a project, containing some shell scripts and an extra directory with LaTeX documentation.

The diretory structure could look like this

```
.../topdir/
      |
      |-Makefile
      |
      |--data/
      |    |-filea
      |    |-fileb
      |
      |--latex/
      |    |-example.tex
      |    |-awesome-style.sty
      |    |-imagea.png
      |    |-Makefile
```

In that `latex`-directory exists a `Makefile` which is working alright, when I `cd` into the directory and call `make clean` or `make example` ...

Now, I want the `Makefile` in the topdir to be the master makefile.  When I am in that directory and say e.g. `make example` the recipe should be, to change into the `latex` directory and run `make` from there, hence using `latex/Makefile`.

**EDIT**  Of course, when I say `make clean` in the topdir Makefile, I want the it to also run `make clean` in the `latex` dir.

What is the correct trick?  What must I write in the master makefile?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Although it has no relationship to this question: THANK you very much, defining pagestyles seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
example:
        $(MAKE) -C latex
clean:
        $(MAKE) -C latex clean

.PHONY: example clean
```

will what you asked for.  The `.PHONY` is optional but a good idea.

Comment: It seems you could easily extrapolate my answer to find the solution you are looking for on your own.  However, I'll edit it.